# How to obtain User Field Properties in Lookup List via Rest Api

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, rest

I have a List (Topics) which has a MultiLookupField to a List named (Speakers)

Speakers has a User Field (UserName).

What I'm trying to do is to read some of the User Fields Properties. Which works when I'm querying the List with the User Field directly:

```
_api/web/getbytitle('Speaker')/items(1)?$select=UserName/Id&$expand=UserName
```

However I'm not able to get the User Field through the Topics list:

These are my desperate attempts which are all not working:

```
_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Topics')/items(1)?$select=Speakers/ID,Speakers/UserName&$expand=Speakers

_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Topics')/items(1)?$select=Speakers/ID,Speakers/UserNameId&$expand=Speakers

_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Topics')/items(1)?$select=Speakers/ID,Speakers/UserName/Id&$expand=Speakers,Speakers/UserName/Id
```

**Edit:**

I'm also facing the same behaviour when I'm trying to select Boolean or Choice Fields in the Lookup List.

Providing a little Image which should show my situation:

[image]

so for clarification my *Topics* List has a MultiLookup Column *Speakers* which is bound to the List *Speakers*. The List *Speakers* has some other fields and a User Field.

And I'm trying to expand some of the User's Field Properties through Rest.

Comment: Can you elaborate on 'not working'?  Are you getting an error? If so, what error?  Are you getting unexpected results?

Comment: I only get 400 Bad Request. The query to field 'xxx' is not valid. When trying to get one of that fields, tested now with Boolean, Choice and User Fields in a Lookup List.

Comment: Have you tested the url to make sure it works in either a browser or a REST app?

Comment: By the way, the first url is valid, the others are not.

Comment: I have tested it in a Browser and an Rest app. I know that they are wrong. But as I didn't get it to work. I have tried and played around with the Url to get it working.

Comment: I misunderstood your question.  I didn't realize the user field was the field being looked up.  Out of curiosity, why lookup to a list of users? Does the lookup list provide additional info?

Comment: One Topic contains 1 or more Speakers. The Speakers List holds the Speakers which are mapped with some specific additional Informations which are not stored in the AD and the Associated User from the AD. If one exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isn't possible expand lookup via Rest Api. Only for user(column default) and field with atribute Deferred.

But have solution for this:

loop items and get all items and selecting only the SpeakersID

```
_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('Topics')/items?$select=SpeakersId
```

will return as show image below:
[image: json topics and speakers]

but isn't suficient for get user info:

Update(2):

then you will use 2 rest api for your case.

```
_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('Topics')/items?$select=SpeakersId;
_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('Speakers')/items(n)?$select=UserName/Id,UserName/Title&$expand=UserName;
```

> logic generic.

```
url="..../_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('Topics')/items?$select=SpeakersId";
call ajax....(sucess:getItems,...)
function getItems(data){
  var items = data.d.results; // array of items
  var item;
  for(var i =0;i<items.length;i++){
    item = items[i];
    speakers = item.SpeakersId.results;
    for(var j =0;j<speakers.length;j++){
      var LookupID_Speaker = speakers[j];
      var url = "_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('Speakers')/items("+LookupID_Speaker +")?$select=UserName/Id,UserName/Title&$expand=UserName";
      // set ajax async to false;
      call ajax....(sucess:getProperties,...)
    }
  }
}

function getProperties(data){
  var UserID = data.UserNameId;
  var UserTitle = data.Title;

  // do you code here.

}
```

Comment: So when i'm facing Boolean,Choice,User and Lookup Fields in a Lookup List this results everytime in 3 calls to get the values? That's really an awful way if there is no other possibility.

Comment: yeap this is terrible to implementation to get user information :/ but not impossible.

Comment: see my update post, have tested here and work fine.

Answer (score 0):

The REST API doesn't seem to want to fetch the `UserName` field, try `Name` instead and you should get the value that's actually in `UserName` even though my User Information List has a field called `Name` with a different value in it.

I find `Id` works when proper cased, but not upper (so no `ID`)

Try this query:

```
_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Topics')/items(1)?
    $select=Speakers/Id,Speakers/Name&$expand=Speakers
```

This works with the standard "User Information List" fields for Users. It may not work the same on a customized list holding user information.

Comment: This doesn't work either please see my edit it may clarifies my problem.